# What's up with ApplyPropertyValue() when used with RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

Apparently, when I use the function `ApplyPropertyValue()` on a `RichTextBox`, `Selection.Select` stops working correctly.
I've got a RichTextBox filled with some text.

```
string selectText(int index, int length)
        {
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(TB.Document.ContentStart, TB.Document.ContentEnd);
            if (textRange.Text.Length >= (index + length))
            {
                TextPointer start = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                TextPointer end = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(index + length, LogicalDirection.Backward);
                TB.Selection.Select(start, end);
                return TB.Selection.Text;
            }
            return null;
        }
display.Text = selectText(6, 8);
// display contains the string "arranged"
TB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty, "Red");
// display now contains the string "arrang" (should be "arranged")
display.Text = selectText(6, 8);
```

`display` is a TextBlock used to display values of variables for debugging purposes, `TB` is a RichTextBox.

`selectText(i,length)` function works fine if used without ApplyPropertyValue() and always returns the correct substring of the text in `TB`.

After the above code executes, `display` contains "arrang" instead of "arranged". Also, if I remove the ApplyPropertyValue() statement, `display` will contain "arranged" as expected.

What's up the ApplyPropertyValue() thing? Am I missing something here?